# My arduino gives me several avrdude erros

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avrdude, visualstudio

For school we program an arduino with visual studio and micro visio. Since a few days ago my arduino wont run the code of the arduino. At first it didnt give any errors until i tried to upload a code with arduino ide itself.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM3"
Or saying that the acces is denied. I confirmed that my arduino is the COM3 port. The weird part is that on another pc it works fine. On the laptop where my arduino isnt working i did a loopback test following. https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360020366520.
This went without a problem. I reinstalled the IDE and drivers but sadly this didnt help either. If i try a class mates his arduino it wont work either. If some one has information on how to fix this problem that would be nice. If there is some extra information needed that wont be a problem either.

Comment: The COM port can only be used by one program at a time. Typically, the above error happens if either program (Visual Studio or the Arduino IDE) have the serial console open and you try to program the Arduino using the other.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will admit at first i didn't do this but after a few times i did close the other and i still got the same problems.

Comment: If you connect and disconnect your Uno, the COM3 shows up and disappears, respectively? Also, when you are using Arduino IDE, the visual studio is not running? Check this [link](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGw9CAG&l=en-US) if you want to find out if some other process is using your COM port.